# Remove date from log files

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have an irc log as follows

```
04/14/13 21:38<@Hamatti> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
04/14/13 21:39<@Hamatti> consectetur adipiscing elit.
04/14/13 21:45<@Hamatti> Duis facilisis convallis lacus
```

**EDIT1**. sorry, I was not clear with my intentions. So I would want the output for the previous to be

```
21:38<@Hamatti> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
21:39<@Hamatti> consectetur adipiscing elit.
21:45<@Hamatti> Duis facilisis convallis lacus
```

so the time is important.

**EDIT2**
There is also part of the logs, the earlier ones in format

```
20:12<@Hamatti> Something.
20:13<@Hamatti> Funny.
20:13<@Hamatti> Happened.
```

and I need those lines to be non-modified.

and since my old logs are in format with no date stamp, I would like to remove the date from later logs.

```
sed 's/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}//g' logfile
```

Regex in the sed seems to work in regex testers but this sed is not doing anything. I wonder where is the problem? Any tips with bash tools (sed, awk, etc) are highly welcomed. Since only part of the logs have the date, I can't use something like

```
awk '{$1 = ""; print}'
```

because I would need the checking first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sed command will do the job:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[^<]*//' logfile
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, this will only clear date part and preserve the timestamp:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^[^ ]* //' logfile
```

**EDIT 2:** Based on your 2nd time edited question:

```
sed -i.bak 's#^[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]* ##' logfile
```

OR use extended regex capability in sed like this:

**Mac:**

```
sed -E -i.bak 's#^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2} ##' logfile
```

**Linux:**

```
sed -r -i.bak 's#^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2} ##' logfile
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, but I realised that I was unclear. I want only the date to go but save the timestamp. See my updated original. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Oh, I still have to edit. Since part of the data has the date and part doesn't, the latest sed removes timestamp from those where there is no date.

Comment: Thank you again for your time and effort.

Comment: You can modify the first edit to avoid timestamps: `sed 's#^../[^ ]* ##'` (The samples show the first date element padded to two places so we don't need to get fancy there - unless the sample is wrong, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

The cut command is easy to apply here:

```
cut -d " " -f "2-" logfile
```

It means:

*If every line is split by an space (delimiter, -d option) then take all items from the second one onwards.*

Comment: I found the `cut` is much easier to understand than the `sed`. Upvoted!